# Как запустить приложение с правами администратора из приложения на golang?

Tags: golang

Как указать приложению golang, что ”вот этот” файл надо запустить с правами администратора?
Как это реализовать?

Answer (score 1):

Просто запустите ваше Go-приложение от имени администратора. В самом приложении проверить пользователя на администратора можно с помощью [`os/user`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/user/):

```
usr, err := user.Current()
if err != nil {
    //hundle error
}
if usr.Username != "root" {
    os.Exit(0)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Для этого необходимо GO-приложение запускать от имени администратора, в результате, все что оно(приложение) будет делать, оно будет делать с правами администратора, в том числе и запускать другие приложения.

Comment: мне нужно что-то в самом приложении прописать, что б оно только с правами администратора запускалось и сперва выскакивало окошко запуска с такими правами,если включена защита винды. В C#  есть манифест и там указываешь, а здесь не нашёл, что писать